# Find elements inside div?

Tags: javascript

I would like to find input with name="bid" and div with class="item-i" inside div class="section-header"
I need this on javascript without any outer src.
example: ajax

```
<div class="section-header" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold">
        <form action="index.php?mod=auction" method="post" id="auctionForm14363131" data-item_name="Samnit" data-item_szint="88" data-item_sebzés="0" data-item_páncél="0" data-item_erő="0" data-item_fürgeség="0" data-item_ügyesség="0" data-item_alkat="0" data-item_karizma="0" data-item_intelligencia="0" data-item_gyógyítás="0" data-item_életerő="0" data-item_veszély="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="auctionid" value="14363131">
            <input type="hidden" name="qry" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="itemType" value="15">
            <input type="hidden" name="itemLevel" value="86">
            <input type="hidden" name="itemQuality" value="-1">
            <input type="hidden" name="buyouthd" id="buyout14363131" value="0">
            <div class="auction_item_div">
            <div style="position:relative">
                <div style="left:0px;top:0px" class="item-i-15-5 ui-draggable ui-droppable item-i-blue ui-draggable-handle" data-content-type="16384" data-content-size="1" data-enchant-type="null" data-price-gold="11124" data-tooltip="[[[&quot;Samnit&quot;,&quot;#5159F7; text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000, 0 0 2px #5159F7&quot;],[&quot;\u00c9leter\u0151: 4416&quot;,&quot;#BA9700&quot;],[&quot;Er\u0151: 207&quot;,&quot;#BA9700&quot;],[&quot;\u00dcgyess\u00e9g: 281&quot;,&quot;#BA9700&quot;],[&quot;F\u00fcrges\u00e9g: 180&quot;,&quot;#BA9700&quot;],[&quot;Alkat: 115&quot;,&quot;#BA9700&quot;],[&quot;Karizma: 115&quot;,&quot;#BA9700&quot;],[&quot;Intelligencia: 143&quot;,&quot;#BA9700&quot;],[&quot;Szint 88&quot;,&quot;#808080&quot;],[&quot;\u00c9rt\u00e9ke 12.793 <div class=\&quot;icon_gold\&quot;><\/div>&quot;,&quot;#DDDDDD&quot;],[&quot;Megjegyz\u00e9s: Ez a zsoldos melletted fog harcolni. Ehhez a ``Kazamata karaktered\u00b4\u00b4 adatlapj\u00e1n magad mell\u00e9 kell venned \u0151t.&quot;,&quot;#808080&quot;,250]]]" data-comparison-tooltip="null" data-level="88" data-quality="1" data-hash="c4m-f-5-8l0-1h-14-71-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-1-0-0-0" data-amount="1" data-position-x="1" data-position-y="1" data-measurement-x="1" data-measurement-y="1" data-basis="15-5"></div>                            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="auction_bid_div">
        <div>
        <span style="color:#8A0808;">..</span><br><span class="gca-auction-bad-price">
        <img alt="" src="..." align="absmiddle" border="0"></span><span class="gca-auction-price-value-percent">(108%)</span></div>
        <div>....                               : 13.776&nbsp;
        <img alt="" src="..." title="Arany" align="absmiddle" border="0"></div>
        <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="bid_amount" size="8" onkeypress="return checkAndSubmitForm(event, 'auctionForm14363131');" value="13776">
        <input type="button" value="Ajánlat" name="bid" class="awesome-button gca-auction-can-buy">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

How i can solve this?
Thanks before!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.querySelector` assuming you know `CSS` this is very easy. Here are some examples

```js
document.querySelector('[name="bid"]');
document.querySelector('.section-header .item-i');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like `document.querySelector` then query it using css selector.

it simply like you query using jQuery, but the result is either null or an element.

```
var bid = document.querySelector("[name='bid']")
if (bid) console.log(bid.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".section-header form div[class*='item-i']");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[value*='Ajánlat']");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    alert(items[i].getAttribute("data-tooltip"));
    alert(buttons[i].value);
}
```